# How to get crash log in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to get the crash log from my app? I know that we can get the exception handler by NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler, but I want to get the crash file which could be found by Organizer. I want to access that file and send to my server. Is there any supported SDK to do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popular service HockeyApp is based on open source software that has it's own client that lives in your app and a basic server to collect crash reports from your app.

Check out their github account for more information on setting it all up.

https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit

Comment: Thanks Jessedc. I notice that the HockeyApp use the PCLCrashReporter to do the job. It's a good project but it seems that it also use the NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler to get the exception. I want some method to access the crash log which the iOS generated and stored. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot access the crash report that is generated by iOS from your app. The crash report is located outside of your apps sandbox. That's why projects like PLCrashReporter are required to get crash data. In addition PLCrashReporter sometimes even shows more and better information than iOS own reports, by showing the Last Exception Backtraces more often in my experience than iOS shows it.